# How to assign a random port number to a gRPC server instance (in Node)?

Tags: node.js, http, server, microservices, grpc

When starting an http server in Node.js, developers can listen on a randomly available port by passing `0` like so:

```
const http = require('http')
const service = require('../my/service);
const server = http.createServer(service)
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 0) // <-- Random port by default!
```

I wonder how I can do the same thing with gRPC? Something like...

```
const grpc = require('grpc')
const services = require('./service_grpc_pb')
const server = new grpc.Server()
server.addService(services.MyService, { ... })
server.bind('0.0.0.0:0', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure())
server.start()
```

Does that work? I've yet to find out. My goal is to get a random port and then query the server to get the assigned port in order to register the service with a central microservice registry.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: "Does that work? I've yet to find out."  Try it and see?

Comment: Indeed, I did try it out...@Brad. I'm guilty of being 100% n00b. Caught me red-handed. Sometimes I'm also guilty of asking so I don't have to do the work to find out myself. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use a port number of `0` to assign a random port to a gRPC server. The `server.bind` method returns the port number that was actually assigned. If you want to use the `bindAsync` method instead, the assigned port number will be passed to the callback.